# getting error Missing calls inside every { ... } block in writing unit test cases in kotlin + Mockk + Junit5

Tags: kotlin, junit5, mockk

the function I am testing,

```
class FileUtility {
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun deleteFile(filePath: String) {
            try {
                val file = getFileObject(filePath)
                file.delete()
            } catch (ex :Exception) {
                log.error("Exception while deleting the file", ex)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Unit test,

```
@Test
fun deleteFileTest() {
    val filePath = "filePath"
    val file = mockk<File>()
    every { getFileObject(filePath) } returns file
    deleteFile(filePath)
    verify { file.delete() }
}
```

getting the following error on running this test case

```
 io.mockk.MockKException: Missing calls inside every { ... } block.
```

is this any bug or am I writing wrong test case?

Comment: where does your `getFileObject ` function reside?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming `getFileObject` is a top level function in `FileUtility.kt` file, you need to mock  module wide functions with `mockkStatic(...)` with argument as the module’s class name.

> For example “pkg.FileKt” for module File.kt in the pkg package.

```
@Test
fun deleteFileTest() {
    val file = mockk<File>()
    mockkStatic("pkg.FileKt")
    
    val filePath = "filePath"
    every { getFileObject(filePath) } returns file
    every {file.delete()} answers {true}

    deleteFile(filePath)
    
    verify { file.delete() }
}
```